# UI element are blocked on programmatically opened QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qdialog

There is MainWindow inherited from QMainWindow. And there is SettingsDialog inherited from QDialog. From MainWindow user can open SettingsDialog as modal dialog by clicking "Settings" button.

```
void MainWindow::showSettingsDialog()
{
    SettingsDialog settingsDialog(this);
    settingsDialog.exec();
}
```

App has tray notifications. If user clicks notification ReadWindow (inherited from QWidget) will be opened as not modal window.

```
void MainWindow::onTrayMessageClicked()
{
    activateWindow();
    ReadWindow *readWindow = new ReadWindow(this);
    readWindow->show();
}
```

Now if user clicks tray notification when SettingsDialog is opened ReadWindow will be opened in front of SettingsDialog. User can activate ReadWindow, but all UI elements (for example all buttons) in ReadWindow are blocked(i.e. buttons are not clickable) while SettingsDialog is open.

How to open ReadWindow under SettingsDialog and do it not selectable by user (since SettingsDialog is modal)?

Edit: *My goal is: open ReadWindow under any other modal windows and user must not interact with ReadWindow until he closes all modal windows*

Comment: I tried to call `void QWidget::raise()` from settingsDialog. It brings SettingsDialog to front but ReadWindow still can be activated.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. But I didn't fix problem yet. So still waiting for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make the settings dialog modal at all? Is there a special reason? Make the settings dialog non-modal if possible.

Anyway your ReadWindow should get the the SettingsDialog as a parent, not the MainWindow. Currently you are passing `this` (which is the MainWindow) to the constructor of the ReadWindow which does not reflect the desired order. Maybe this also resolves your modality problem.

**UPDATE**

Now I understand what you want to achieve.

Maybe you can bring your SettingsDialog back to front using Qwidget:raise(). Another solution could be to set a flag and to open the Reader window after the Settings Dialog is closed.

However I would try to avoid that uncommon behaviour completely. Sure there is no more inutitive GUI design?

Comment: Logic of App requires to do SettingsDialog as modal. So I can't do it not modal.

Comment: ReadWindow and SettingsDialog windows are independent from each other. If I set SettingDialog as parent of ReadWindow, when user closes SettingsDialog ReadWindow also will be closed. It shuldn't.

Comment: I don't think they are independent. SettingsDialog opens the ReadDialog while the rest if the GUI is locked. This actually means Read is kind of child of Settings. The visual/user-side order should correspond to the logical/object-side order. Otherwise you will experience problems like you described above.

Comment: Try my suggestion and tell me if it solves the modality problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. As I said ReadWindow must stay after closing SettingsDialog. I just want to do SettingsDialog as modal for ReadWindow. So your suggestion not solved modality problem.

Comment: You could simply remove the 'this' parameter but you would get an independent top level window... if this is what you want. See Matthias' solution.

Comment: I tried to call `void QWidget::raise()` and `void QWidget::activateWindow()` from settingsDialog. It brings SettingsDialog to front but ReadWindow still can be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void MainWindow::showSettingsDialog()
{
    SettingsDialog settingsDialog(this);
    settingsDialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    settingsDialog.show();
}

void MainWindow::onTrayMessageClicked()
{
    activateWindow();
    ReadWindow *readWindow = new ReadWindow();
    readWindow->show();
}
```

From the Docs:
*Dialogs can be application modal (the default) or window modal.*

settingsDialog:
*The window is modal to a single window hierarchy and blocks input to its parent window, all grandparent windows, and all siblings of its parent and grandparent windows.*

readwindow:
*Is not a child of Maindialog so it is not blocked.*

Hope that helps...

Comment: Yes, your answer unblocks UI element. But my question is: How to open ReadWindow under SettingsDialog and do it not selectable by user (do SettingsDialog modal relative to ReadWindow also)?